# Android app glitch reviews when much better on Apple in Codenameone app

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

Please could i have some advice from those who have been building apps for longer than myself. After 18 months of developing 2 quite complex CN1 apps, available on IOS and Android stores, I get starkly different customer feedback.

On both stores i get similar download levels (<10 a day). 
From Google Play i receive nearly zero revenue and 1 and 2 star reviews, citing that the app of full of glitches, 'does not work' and freezes - but the same time reviews say they really like the app if it worked. I do not receive any examples of information to guide me on where to fix. It runs fine in my simulator (even slow network mode) and on my own Android device. Hence i'm not sure the best way forward, which is the advice i am after.
On IOS i receive mixed reviews, generally 2-4 stars but i get some revenue.

FYI, the app uses Rest web services to send data to/from my cloud database, so network is likely a cause, although i cannot reproduce. I can imagine customers clicking a button many times on the trot if the network is slow resulting in the transaction or screen showing multiple times. But just a guess. The cloud server is running fine with no spike in CPU or memory. I have tried to keep physical JSON network traffic loads small so that should be fine.

Would you agree that the next steps are to:

1. Verify the network traffic numbers, using the network monitor in the simulator and get these down if poss.
2. Check that buttons disable themselves when pressed to avoid double tap.
3. Write to a local storage log of timings when a user moves between screens, and pass that to my database on app exit, for my analysis on slow navigation.

Are there any other tips and tricks please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using something like the [rating widget](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rating-widget.html) to track user satisfaction. When a user provides a low rating ask him to email you personally so you can discuss the problems.

I would also suggest crash protection. Most of these cases occur due to on device exceptions that are hard to pinpoint and generally happen more on Android. Crash protection will send out emails with such details. Also check out the ANR/Crashes in Google Play's developer console to see if there's something you can improve.

Also you can add the play store link, I'll take a look and see if something pops out for me.

Comment: I have the Ratings Widget, though apple wouldn't allow my app if i didn't redirect to the store from a low rating. The ANR report shows only 2 ANRs every week (against approx 50 downloads a week) with no crashes. The Dev Console shows one 'Input Dispatching Timed out at ...RewardsStub[195]' - odd as i don't have that class. I was next going to look at your Performance Monitor for clues. It would be fantastic if you had time - it is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinksmart.superstars.rewards   Thanks

Comment: I took a bit of a look at the app and have a lot of thoughts about why there might be a problem. The main issue with the app is with the UI/UX which is too close to iOS styling and doesn't respect Android conventions (e.g. back button). It's also lacks padding and feels cramped. You also use infinite progress a lot which on a slow network can give the impression of the application being stuck.

Comment: I'll have a look at Android vs IOS styling. Perhaps i was taking WriteOnceRunAnywhere too literally and that platforms needed more UX care. I will look at a UX overhaul of the app to de-clutter pages and having more space. Yes i use InfiniteProgress on load of all pages as i wanted to let the user know to wait for page load. This is relevant https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dont-block-the-ui.html, and says essentially to use sparingly (though your guides say it is good to use). So perhaps i'll drop this and just load it serially and focus on network traffic. Thanks for taking the time.